# SharePoint Designer - The admin disabled this functionality for this workflow

Tags: error, designer

I get this error message when working with a workflow in SharePoint designer. Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

[image]

Comment: What are you doing to cause this error?  What action are you trying to perform?  There is not enough information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `user-defined workflows for all sites on this web application` has been disabled , to enable it do the following

- Go to Central Administration.
- Click on Application Management, and then click on Manage Web Applications.
- Select the Web Application for which the SharePoint Designer workflows must be enabled.
- In the ribbon interface, click on the General Settings drop down.
  Click on Workflow.
- Select yes under the "Enable user-defined workflows for all sites on this web application?" option.

[image]

For more details check [Troubleshoot workflow errors](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Troubleshoot-workflow-errors-8FCF47E5-A410-4714-880B-2611B18A56CE)